# how to call the current time NOW() in protege SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

I am trying to calculate the duration time in SPARQL protege
I need to call the NOW() so that I can find the difference time.
I tried
PREFIX ofn:http://www.ontotext.com/sparql/functions/
afn:now(), I get error unknown

I am using Protege version 5.5.0
Also I have tried
ofn:millis-from-duration()
also it is unknow function

what else can I try?

Comment: `http://www.ontotext.com/sparql/functions/` is a namespace from the GraphDB triple store - that has nothing to do with Protege which is backed by Sesame/RDF4j RDF API - `now()` is SPARQL standard, no need for a prefix, but if you need those non-standard functions like shown [here](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/devhub/time-functions.html) then you also have to use their product which is GraphDB

Comment: It seems that `NOW()` is not supported by the SPARQL plugin (due to [this](https://github.com/protegeproject/rdf-library/issues/6), I suppose). However, `NOW()` is supported by the Snap SPARQL plugin. But you have to add at least one triple pattern. Like this: `SELECT DISTINCT ?now WHERE {?x owl:equivalentClass owl:Thing . BIND (NOW() AS ?now)}`

Comment: @StanislavKralin I'm pretty sure it is supported. Protege depends on Sesame 2.7.3 which in fact does support everything except the missing cast functions mentioned in the Github issue you're referring to. See https://github.com/ansell/openrdf-sesame/blob/2.7.3/core/queryalgebra/evaluation/src/main/java/org/openrdf/query/algebra/evaluation/function/datetime/Now.java - the problem the TO did was to use the Apache JEna prefix, i.e. `afn:now()` as well as some other GraphDB specific cusotm functions with the `ofn:` prefix which are not part of standard SPARQL.

Answer (score 1):

Just `NOW()`. It's core built-in function in SPARQL 1.1, there's no need to use a custom prefixed function.

Comment: unfortunately does not work it said undefined function

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Protege to me. I'd report it to them directly.